# Why Angular always redirecting to main page?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-ui-router

Always I trying to GET `'/'` it shows `static-root-component` (component of my main page),
but when it is `'/welcome'` page immediately redirecting to `'/'` and also loading `static-root-component` instead of `welcome-component`

Initially I wanted to redirect users to welcome page if they aren't authorized, but login status only can be checked within JavaScript. After JS got info about login status it decides to redirect using `location.replace("/welcome")`, but... Angular again goes to `'/'`

> "Funny" fact: there isn't any routing problems during debug with `ng serve` but it always happens with `ng build`

I don't know what's gone wrong and there is `app.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { StaticRootComponent } from './static-root/static-root.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './welcome/welcome.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpService } from './http.service';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StaticRootComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    StaticRootComponent,
    WelcomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoute),
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [HttpService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule { }
```

I can drop any other Angular file if needed

Comment: did you try:
`const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '/', component: StaticRootComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '/welcome', component: WelcomeComponent }
];`

Comment: Share full code.

Comment: @milan, obviously I tried it, but compiler says: `Invalid configuration of route '/welcome': path cannot start with a slash`

Comment: Did you try to add the `welcome` route first ?

Comment: @Shakthifuture, what files are you want to see? I generated project with `ng new` and hasn't edited another files

Comment: try to do this

const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StaticRootComponent},
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent }
];

Comment: @Prakash Harvani, your answer is the same as in my code that doesn't work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project based on MEAN (Mongo, Express, Angular and NODEJS)... The last was a source of problem

@Shakthifuture, you said you want to see full code and I started answering:

*"What you wanna to see else? My data and **server** files doesn't affec..."*

and I've starting think "what if affect?": routing in whole of project works by Angular, but all new connection to the site pass NodeJS and Express, so I forgot about *404* case...

**THE PROBLEM:**

In server script file `index.js` of project's root folder a long time ago I've added code about what to do if entered path not found:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('/');
    // IF 404 NOT FOUND
});
```

and above of it something like:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/angular/index.html`)
});
// send index if path is '/'
```

but nothing for `'/welcome'`, that's why redirecting happens

**THE SOLUTION:**

let's add the `'/welcome'` handler:

```
app.get('/welcome', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(`${__dirname}/angular/index.html`)
});
```

(again index.html due to SPA)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, change like below

```
const appRoute: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: StaticRootComponent },
  { path: 'welcome', component: WelcomeComponent },
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

In the component file, inject this like below

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
constructor(
        private router: Router
) {}
```

When you want do navigation use the below code instead of `location.replace("/welcome")`

```
this.router.navigate(['/welcome']);
```

Comment: Checked it. Page still redirecting to `'/'`, as for `this.router.navigate(['/welcome']);` I said that navigating must be controlled by some script. If there's only possible to routing from TS so how to make call from JS to Angular

I think, I made mistake in my code while editing in some TS file so to prove/disprove it I'll regenerate new ng project and piecemeal whole my code

Comment: I did that, check

Answer (score 0):

Check the **Module** you trying to instantiate in the *constructor* of the **Component** linked to the **Routing Path** you are trying to access

In this case:

**Our Component:** *example.component.ts*

**Our Module:** *HttpClientModule that contains HttpClient*

**Our Routing Path:** *"/example"*

and make sure that Module is already existing in the **app.module.ts** , here is an example:

---

## example.component.ts

---

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'; //child of HttpClientModule 

@Component({selector: 'app-example',templateUrl: './example.component.html', styleUrls: ['./example.component.css']})

export class ExampleComponent{
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
}
```

now let's see both examples of app module with and without the Module import and see the difference

---

## app.module.ts

#### Without including HttpClientModule in imports array

---

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [BrowserModule,...],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> > In this case loading the "/example" path will redirect you to the main page path which is usually "/" and that's because **example.component.ts** is using **HttpClient** (child of **HttpClientModule**) but not finding it in **app.module.ts** .

---

## app.module.ts

#### Including HttpClientModule in imports array

---

```
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'; //Import that module you willing to use

@NgModule({
  declarations: [...],
  imports: [BrowserModule,HttpClientModule,...], //add the module we currently using
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

> > In this case loading the "/example" path will work properly since we added the required module in **app.module.ts**.

If that's your case that would definitely fix your problem unless you have something else forcing the redirection to home page "index.html" or any other path, else if that didn't fix your problem read the following notes:

> Make sure to check there are no redirections in the **app-routing.module.ts** routes array like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent},
    { path: '/example', redirectTo: '' }
];
```

it should only be like so

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {path: 'example', component: ExampleComponent}
];
```

> Also make sure there is no routing behaviour causing the redirection like @angular/router through something like **this.router.navigate(['/'])**

> PS: SAME ISSUE COULD IMPLY IF YOU USING A SERVICE THAT'S USING A MODULE WHICH IS NOT ADDED TO MODULE IMPORTS IN **app.module.ts**